# "can include" vs. "may include"

Tags: meaning, difference

> A **can** include B

> A **may** include B

In the above sentences, "can" and "may" are being used to indicate a possibility ("can" is not indicating a capability, which I know is another possible meaning of "can").

I would like to know if there is any subtle difference in meaning between the possibility indicated by "can" and the one indicated by "may". Or, is it possible to use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, one is describing contents or ingredients, and terminology becomes important. *A* or *B* might be large categories, small groups, or individual things. Using names for them categorizes somewhat (*boulders, rocks, pebbles, gravel, sand*) but there may be some pebbles mixed in with the gravel, hence a warning:

- *Gravel may contain pebbles.*
- *Gravel can contain pebbles.*

*May* is more common for CYA announcements like this, but *can* means the same thing, but is less common in affirmative epistemic senses. Normally epistemic *can* is restricted to negative contexts

- *This can't be the place!* versus **This can be the place!*

but here it's OK because (as you say) it can't be ability *can* because there's no agent subject, and it can't be deontic *can* because there's no authority. All of them display possibility or probability -- all  modals do. *May* and *can* (and their mates, *might* and *could)* are "Possible" or "Diamond **♢** modals, distinguished from "Necessary" or "Square" **⬜︎** modals like *shall, should, will, would,* and *must*.

Comment: The "diamond" and "square" names stand for the [modal logic symbols](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for possible and necessary. [Modals](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) of each type work differently in some respects.

Comment: I hadn't heard of the modal logic symbols before and think they're interesting. "CYA" here means ["cover your ass"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Cover+your+ass)?

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, you're right. You can find out about the symbols in [the Logic Guide](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and about modality generally [here.](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Without your caveat about "*can*", the difference would be:

- "*A can include B*" describes something being allowed or possible
- "*A may include B*" describes a probability